# Give specific options for a struct in C++

Tags: c++

I was attempting to create a struct in C++ that was a single Ternary digit. It is similiar to a bit but has three different values instead of two. Is there any way of limiting the options to -1, 0 or 1. Any help is appreciated.

what I have so far is:

```
struct trit {
     char digit; // I dont just want a character. I only want either -1, 0 or 1
};
```

Comment: I think searching first would've helped here. Anyway, note that `char` isn't suitable for signed values generally, as it has implementation-defined signage or lack thereof, so it might be an unsigned type. If you want to store values less than 0, use `signed char`; or for values greater than zero that might be greater than 127, `unsigned char`. Just use `char` for actual characters as part of strings, not for numbers.

Comment: What operations does this digit need to do? Should it work like an imaginary "int2_t"?
Could an enum class be a solution?
Maybe you need to implement an additional class with the required operator methods to do calculations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try [enumerators](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/enum).

```
enum Ternary_digit { down = -1,zero = 0, up = 1 };
```

Answer (score 4):

The classic way to provide functionality is through functions.

Alternatively, a scope enum could provide you with a limited range if values.

```
enum class Trit: signed char { minus_one=-1, zero=0, one=1 };
```

you could then provide extended functionality through functions.